# Uglifiy scripts using jhipster 4.14

Tags: jhipster

I have a question about an earlier version of JHipster with AngularJS .
considering that the generator is using uglify method. The thing is the uglify worked and generated vendor.js and app.js, but the browser is making a folder named "source" which showing my source code which doesn't exist under my server.  Is it ok that this is happening?

Screenshot showing the source folder:

[image: Screenshot showing source folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being able to see the `source` folder and de-uglified JS is normal when the source maps are available.  You can see the map by opening the JS file directly in the browser and appending `.map` to the URL.  For more information, see the [Chrome Developer Tools documentation about source maps](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps#source_maps_in_devtools_sources_panel).

To prevent source maps from being generated and packaged into the WAR for an AngularJS JHipster project, you comment out or remove `.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))` in `gulp/build.js`

Comment: thank you  for your help . so there is no way to ugilify scripts without folder source being generated ?

Comment: See the second part of my answer.  That will prevent `gulp` from outputting the source maps, which stops the `source` folder appearing